# File's modification date in C#

Tags: c#, file

I have to write an application, which will compare the modification date of two files. These files are Excel workbooks. The first file is located on a local drive and the second on a LAN network.

Any hints, how to write this app? There's no need to open these files, just to check the date from file attributes.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
System.IO.FileInfo file1 = new System.IO.FileInfo(file1Name);
System.IO.FileInfo file2 = new System.IO.FileInfo(file2Name);
if(file1.LastWriteTime != file2.LastWriteTime)
    //Do some stuff.
```

Answer (score 2):

System.IO Namespace - FileInfo Class